# "'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type" in code with no void*'s?

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, void-pointers

I have a problem in my code. In **Xcode** or using the **C++11** compiler, this code works well. However, when I am submitting this code to an Online Judge, the verdict shows **"Compile Error"**. I think they use the **C++4.7.1** compiler, which when I tried to compile it (using Ideone), it says:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'void printArray(int)':
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
prog.cpp:27: error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
```

This makes no sense because there are no `void*`'s anywhere in this program.

I don't have any inkling what to change though. It would be great if you guys help me to solve this. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <tgmath.h>

int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int initial = 1;
int tmp;
int total[500];

using namespace std;

void swap(int x, int y){
    int temp = array[x];
    array[x]=array[y];
    array[y]=temp;

    return;
}

void printArray(int size){

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        //cout<<array[i]<<" ";
        tmp= array[i];
        tmp= (tmp* (pow(10.0,(size-i-1))));  // <--- Error here
        total[initial]=total[initial]+ tmp;
    }
    initial++;
    tmp=0;
    //cout<<endl;
}

void permute(int k,int size){
    int i;
    if (k==0) printArray(size);
    else{
        for (i=k-1;i>=0;i--){
            swap(i,k-1);
            permute(k-1,size);
            swap(i,k-1);
        }
    }

    return;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    int i = left, j = right;
    int tmp;
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr, i, right);
}

int main(){
    int countertest;
    cin>>countertest;
    int ak, asize;

    for(int a= 0; a<countertest; a++){

        initial = 1;
        std::fill(total, total+500, 0);
        cin>>asize>>ak;
        permute(asize,asize);

        quickSort(total, 1, initial-1);

        int arraydex [10000], temp = total[ak];
        for(int z = asize; z>=0; z--){
            arraydex[z] = temp % 10;
            temp /= 10;
        }

        for(int bc = 1; bc<=asize; bc++){
            cout<<arraydex[bc]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wait. Are you sure you're posting your original code? I don't see any `void*` here.

Comment: (I complained that the OP nevered declare `tmp` in `printArray`, but it's global.) Also, do not include both `math.h` and `cmath`.

Comment: @EricJablow it is a global variable

Comment: try `pow(10` instead of `pow(10.0`

Comment: It looks like `#include <tgmath.h>` may be an issue when I remove that include the error goes away.

Comment: yeah, this is the original one... thats why i am confused...

Comment: @MarkGarcia- I didn't believe this was the original code until I tried to compile and run it and got the same errors back.  The real explanation is surprisingly complicated, and I learned yet another way to hurt yourself in C and C++ today when figuring out the answer!

Comment: Good find Shafik.  C++ doesn't need tgmath.h - it's macro hackery only need in C to provide compile-time polymorphic math functions (i.e. same function name works on float, double...).

Comment: This article goes into the history of the tgmath header: http://carolina.mff.cuni.cz/~trmac/blog/2005/the-ugliest-c-feature-tgmathh/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell `#include <tgmath.h>` is the issue, and you can remove `#include <math.h>` as well, `#include <cmath>` should be sufficient.

If you include the proper C++ header file `#include <ctgmath>` it looks like it is ok as well.

Answer (score 12):

The issue here is a conflict between `<tgmath.h>` and `<cmath>` / `<math.h>`.

Here's what I've found when opening up the source file to `<tgmath.h>` on my Linux system:

```
#define pow(Val1, Val2) __TGMATH_BINARY_REAL_IMAG (Val1, Val2, pow, cpow)
```

This is important - it's redefining `pow` to use this other macro.  This is *immediately* a problem, because it's `#define`-ing away the normal `pow` function.

So what does this function do?  Well, let's look at `__TGMATH_BINARY_REAL_IMAG`:

```
# define __TGMATH_BINARY_REAL_IMAG(Val1, Val2, Fct, Cfct) \
 (__extension__ (((sizeof (__real__ (Val1)) > sizeof (double)       \
       || sizeof (__real__ (Val2)) > sizeof (double))       \
      && __builtin_classify_type (__real__ (Val1)       \
          + __real__ (Val2)) == 8)    \
     ? ((sizeof (__real__ (Val1)) == sizeof (Val1)        \
   && sizeof (__real__ (Val2)) == sizeof (Val2))        \
  ? (__typeof ((__tgmath_real_type (Val1)) 0        \
       + (__tgmath_real_type (Val2)) 0))        \
    __tgml(Fct) (Val1, Val2)            \
  : (__typeof ((__tgmath_real_type (Val1)) 0        \
       + (__tgmath_real_type (Val2)) 0))        \
    __tgml(Cfct) (Val1, Val2))            \
     : (sizeof (__real__ (Val1)) == sizeof (double)       \
  || sizeof (__real__ (Val2)) == sizeof (double)        \
  || __builtin_classify_type (__real__ (Val1)) != 8     \
  || __builtin_classify_type (__real__ (Val2)) != 8)    \
     ? ((sizeof (__real__ (Val1)) == sizeof (Val1)        \
   && sizeof (__real__ (Val2)) == sizeof (Val2))        \
  ? (__typeof ((__tgmath_real_type (Val1)) 0        \
       + (__tgmath_real_type (Val2)) 0))        \
    Fct (Val1, Val2)              \
  : (__typeof ((__tgmath_real_type (Val1)) 0        \
       + (__tgmath_real_type (Val2)) 0))        \
    Cfct (Val1, Val2))              \
     : ((sizeof (__real__ (Val1)) == sizeof (Val1)        \
   && sizeof (__real__ (Val2)) == sizeof (Val2))        \
  ? (__typeof ((__tgmath_real_type (Val1)) 0        \
       + (__tgmath_real_type (Val2)) 0))        \
    Fct##f (Val1, Val2)             \
  : (__typeof ((__tgmath_real_type (Val1)) 0        \
       + (__tgmath_real_type (Val2)) 0))        \
    Cfct##f (Val1, Val2))))
```

Um... I just don't know what to say here.  This is Cruel and Unusual.

SO what's going on here?  Well, I looked at [the docs for `tgmath.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/tgmath.h.html) and found that this header defines a bunch of type-aware macros for basic functions like `pow` etc. that will determine whether the argument type is a `double`, `float`, etc. and then dispatch the call to the appropriate function.  This is because C doesn't support overloading (though C++ does), so it has to be provided by the magic header file.  The important detail here is that the function should only be called on arguments of type `double`, `float`, or complex versions of these types, and you're passing in an `int`.  Since macro substitution is happening here, the compiler is not even looking at the `cmath` functions and instead just jumping into the C Macro From Hell which tries to introspect on the type.

In short, **don't include this header file in C++!**  It's totally unnecessary in C++ because there's already support for overloaded functions, and there's a `complex` template there to handle complex numbers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 For getting the legwork done to explain this so quickly, I was still working it and probably was not close yet.